# Resolution (or workaround) for using tensorflow-text on WIndows

Tags: tensorflow2.0

`pip install tensorflow_text>=2.0.0rc0` does not work with tensorflow 2.1.0 on Windows. I could not find a solution at https://github.com/tensorflow/text. Can somebody suggest a solution (or workaround apart from switching to Linux)? I want to use universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual which is dependant on tensorflow-text. 
My Tensorflow version: 2.1.0
My pip version: 19.2.3

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu on your computer with [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/wsl/install-win10) and use it. It's a good workaround for applications that run only on Linux.